# Select String in odbc query

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc

is there any posibility to select a string in an odbc query?
i want select the sum of many excel sheets and also need the name of the excel sheet in the resulting pivottable, so i tried something like this:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Sum(`table" & i & "`.`Stunden`), " & GetFilenameFromPath(arrFiles) & " FROM [" & strSheet & "$] `table" & i & "` WHERE `table" & i & "`.`Stunden` IS NOT NULL"
```

but the select statement `" & GetFilenameFromPath(arrFiles) & "`
does not work right... a select of 1 works instead!
e.g:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Sum(`table" & i & "`.`Stunden`), 1 FROM [...]
```

do i have to escape the string in any form?

thanks

Comment: What connection are you running this against? The back-ticks are throwing me. It is perfectly possible with a Jet/ACE connection to select a string: "SELECT 'ABC' As MyBook, F1, F2 FROM [Sheet1$]"

Comment: iam using excel macros and connecting via odbc to an excel sheet... i know this is a little bit ... you know :D but also '" & GetFilenameFromPath(arrFiles) & "' does not work :(

Comment: So are you looping through these sheets and running the SQL or do you want to create a UNION query that select a range or sheet from each sheet in the workbook?

Comment: BTW "does not work" is not sufficiently descriptive, I cannot see how _any_ of your SQL could work :) If you were approaching working, you would need quotes on the table name and a name: `, '" & GetFilenameFromPath(arrFiles) & "' As MySheet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `GetFilenameFromPath` will return you a string, so you need to encase this in quotes:

```
strSQL = "SELECT Sum(`table" & i & "`.`Stunden`), '" & GetFilenameFromPath(arrFiles) & "' FROM...
```

Although, I'd encourage you to be more explicit in your question. Details of the expected output of `GetFilenameFromPath` for you, and a specific error message would be very helpful.

Comment: ok sorry, the error messages of the excel makro editor are not really that what i expect as error message... when i backtick it it works! i had another error in the query which i found later :(

Comment: no worries. Ever thought of using the 'upvote' uption to mark questions as helpful?